# JQuery scroll to div top not working correctly

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery to scroll to div top on click. However it is behaving erratically and only sometimes scrolls to the correct position in the document.

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong?

To give more context: The nav elements are fixed and the scrollTop function works when the page initially loads and you are at the top of the document. However, if you click a nav element anywhere else in the document it does not scroll to the correct position or will scroll back to top.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#artistry").click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#artistry__wrapper").offset().top
            }, 1000);
        });

        $("#resume").click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#resume__wrapper").offset().top
            }, 1000);
        });

       $("#events").click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#events__wrapper").offset().top
            }, 1000);
       });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="nav">
            <div id="artistry" class="nav">Artistry</div>
            <div id="resume" class="nav">Resumé</div>
            <div id="events" class="nav">Events</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: What is `#events__wrapper`? It is not in your html.

Comment: I can include I just didnt think it necessary to include all my html

Comment: Your scrolling code looks good to me. The problem probably comes from something else. Have check your `events_wrapper` positioning? You could use a debugger to intercept the click and display the wrapper offset. If it sometimes scroll to back to the top, it means you should get an offset.top = 0. Then you 'just' have to check your js/css to understand where does this positioning comes from.